# Can you select all child collections of a collection of entities as a single collection?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have a collection of "ParentEntity", each one of which has a collection of "ChildEntity".

I'd like to select ALL of the ChildEntity as a single collection.

```
var children = from p in parents
 select p.Children;
```

Returns a collection of ChildEntity collections?

I'd like to get a single collection of all the Children, rather than a collection of collections.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var children=parents.SelectMany(p=>p.Children)
```

Comment: You know, in all the years I don't think I've ever used this before!